# How is the variance of L2-norm estimated?

Tags: r, statistics, variance

I use the following function to evaluate L2

```
L2norm <- function(ranks, ratings) {
  x <- data.frame(cbind(ranks, ratings))
  colnames(x) <- c('rank', 'rating')
  y <- x %>%
    group_by(rank) %>%
    summarise(
      L2norm = sqrt(sum(rating^2/rank) / sum(1/rank)),
      N = n()
    )
  mean(y$L2norm)
}
```

In short, how is the variance of:

L2norm = sqrt(sum(rating^2/rank) / sum(1/rank))

calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the variance is 1/sqrt(n) * (|| x-x_hat ||_2)^2, where || * ||_2 denotes the Euclidean or L2 norm. This lends itself to the formal definition of variance where var(X)=E[(X-E(X))^2]. If you want to calculate the variance of L2norm, just use R's built-in variance function `var()` on the array of L2norm values.

On an unrelated note, the L2 norm itself is simply the square root of the sum of the elements squared. Is there a particular reason why your L2 norm is scaling each element by rank?

Comment: It's a way of discounting lower ranked items.